# Sort Array Base on the Current Month

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

What I'm trying to do is sort the current array base on the current month and so on. I got the current month but can't figure out a way to sort it to get it to sort properly.

Current Output is (January => December) but want **(August => July).
**What the current month is.

```
<?php

    $mons = array(1 => "January", 2 => "February", 3 => "March", 4 => "April", 5 => "May", 6 => "June", 7 => "July", 8 => "August", 9 => "September", 10 => "October", 11 => "November", 12 => "December");

    $getdate = getdate();
    $months = $getdate['mon'];

    $month_name = $mons[$months];

    echo $month_name; 

    $month_arr = Array( 
        'January' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()) , 
        'February' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'March' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'April' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'May' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'June' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()),
        'July' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'August' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'September' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'October' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'November' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
        'December' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array())
    );

    $date_arr = Array();

    $date_start = 'Aug 02, 2013';
    $date_arr[] = date('M d, Y', strtotime($date_start));


    for ($i=1; $i<=24; $i++){
        $date_temp = date('M d, Y', strtotime($date_arr[$i-1] . "+ 14 day"));
        $month = date('F', strtotime($date_temp));

        $month_arr[$month]['dates'][] = $date_temp;
        $month_arr[$month]['num_dates'] += 1;
        $date_arr[] = $date_temp;
    }

    foreach ($month_arr as $k => $v){
        if (!empty($v)){
            if ($v['num_dates'] != 0){ 
                echo "<BR><BR>Month: " . $k;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to use PHP built-in DateTime object. Here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: If you want to sort an array, have a look at [`usort`](http://php.net/usort).

Comment: sounds like you are looking to filter... not sort...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to loop through your months array starting from the current month.

```
$m  = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $month  = date('F', strtotime("+{$m} months"));
    echo $month . "<br>";
    //$month_arr[$month]; //to access your array
    $m++;

}
```

As suggested, you can also use the DateTime object.